# Drop event not getting fired consistently

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript

Using HTML5 drag and drop stuff. My code looks like:

```
setupDragDrop: ->
  @currentDoc = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getDoc()
  @currentBody = $(@currentDoc).find('body')
  @drag_div = $(JST.drag_message());

  tinyMCE.dom.Event.add(@currentDoc, 'dragover', @dragStarted)
  tinyMCE.dom.Event.add(@currentDoc, 'drop', @dragEnded)

dragStarted: (event) ->
  @setDropArea() unless @dragInProgress
  event.stopPropagation()
  event.preventDefault()

dragEnded: (event) ->
  event.stopPropagation()
  event.preventDefault()
  files = event.dataTransfer.files
  @resetDropStyle()
  @uploadSelectedFiles(files)
```

And I am cancelling `dragover` event and file upload works for most of the stuff and the events get fired as usual. But for something like, Skitch image drag - no `drop` event fires. If you are a Mac User, Skitch is a tool for image editing and lets you drop stuff from the editor itself.

But same drag from Skitch works on Gmail, so I presume I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on, but you may want to try using the [visual event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) bookmarklet to see exactly which events Gmail has bound to the target that you're dropping images on.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only showing a small part of your code, I'll point out a spot where you might have a problem, but you'd need to examine them in greater detail. I'm not overly familiar with CoffeeScript other than it compiles to just plain javascript, so this is pretty much guesswork.

`@setDropArea() unless @dragInProgress`: Assumin that `drop` never fires, is the drop area being properly set? It seems that `unless` would put `@setDropArea()` as never set when `@dragInProgress` is true.

In `dragStarted` and `dragEnded`, add some `console.log` notes to see what methods are firing and when. It may not be that it's not firing, but that it's firing at the wrong time.

Finally, take a look here: http://strd6.com/2011/01/jquery-drag-image-from-desktop-plugin/
This seems to be what you're trying to do (or at least similar) and might give you some hints as to what you're doing wrong.

Best of luck! If you get some results from any of these things, comment and I'll see if I can narrow it down some more.